# How to fix "Invoking "make -j2 -l2"failed" creating rosjava packages (catkin style) in ros indigo?

Tags: catkin-make, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i'm trying to work with rosjava in ros indigo.
I'm following some tutorials to learn how rosjava works, specially with Eclipse like in "Robot Operating System - The Complete Reference - Volume 1" book (page 478).
When i tried to create a rosjava package like in the book i had some error. Than i tried to follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/Creating%20Rosjava%20Packages

and i had exactly this message in the terminal when execute "catkin_make" after created a ROSJAVA project (catkin_create_rosjava_project rosjava_gradle_subproject_a  step)

```
Base path: /home/robo/ws_rosjava
Source space: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/src
Build space: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/build
Devel space: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/devel
Install space: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/robo/ws_rosjava/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/devel;/home/robo/rosjava/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/devel;/home/robo/rosjava/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.19
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - rosjava_catkin_package_a
-- ~~  - rosjava_catkin_package_b
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosjava_catkin_package_a'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosjava_catkin_package_a)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosjava_catkin_package_b'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosjava_catkin_package_b)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/robo/ws_rosjava/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/robo/ws_rosjava/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a
[100%] Gradling tasks for rosjava_catkin_package_a
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: EC parameters error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1872)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1855)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1376)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1348)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:56)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:42)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:57)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: EC parameters error
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11ECPublicKey.getEncodedInternal(P11Key.java:1024)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key.equals(P11Key.java:158)
    at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(ArrayList.java:298)
    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:281)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:239)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1459)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:897)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: EC parameters error
    at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.getAlgorithmParameters(ECParameters.java:284)
    at sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl.<init>(ECPublicKeyImpl.java:59)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11ECPublicKey.getEncodedInternal(P11Key.java:1021)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SunEC
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:83)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:697)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:199)
    at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.getAlgorithmParameters(ECParameters.java:279)
    ... 30 more
make[2]: ** [rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a] Erro 1
make[1]: ** [rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a.dir/all] Erro 2
make: ** [all] Erro 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

This is the same error when i try to create the package like the book's tutorial.

Can someone help me to solve that error???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263208/how-to-fix-%22invoking-%22make--j2--l2%22failed%22-creating-rosjava-packages-(catkin-style)-in-ros-indigo?/) by [eduardo_lasca](https://answers.ros.org/users/30643/eduardo_lasca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install oracle Java 8, it worked for me then.

---

Originally posted by [rhnbmpl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30793/rhnbmpl/) with karma: 38 on 2017-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) on 2017-06-28**:
@rhnbmpl hey, I am wordering which version of Ubuntu are you using? I got the same error

**Comment by [rhnbmpl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30793/rhnbmpl/) on 2017-06-28**:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1

**Comment by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) on 2017-06-28**:
@rhnbmpl Thanks a lot for quick reply. But is there any conflict between Ubuntu 14.04 and jdk 8 since then. Do you remember the way to install it?
I install like this link but it still shows the same error.
[https://gist.github.com/ardyantohermawan/a716c93937830b7631fc3250d21d1bce]

**Comment by [rhnbmpl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30793/rhnbmpl/) on 2017-06-28**:
Install oracle-jdk8 not openjdk8. Here is the [link to install it](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). There has been no conflict till now.

**Comment by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) on 2017-06-28**:
@rhnbmpl installing  oracle-jdk8 definitely solves the above error. But I still struggle to build the android package. Do you have any tips how to build it? Here is the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/Creating%20Android%20Packages) I've followed

**Comment by [rhnbmpl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30793/rhnbmpl/) on 2017-06-28**:
I recommend first installing the [ros environment](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/indigo/Installation%20-%20ROS%20Development%20Environment). After making android core and android interactions, you can open those projects in android studio and make your project on top of those.

**Comment by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) on 2017-06-29**:
thanks a lot, @rhnbmpl

**Comment by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) on 2017-07-01**:
Hey @rhnbmpl, I have another error when add a new project into the android_core. It shows:

```
~/android_core/src/android_core/docs/build.gradle' line: 24
```

Could not find property 'compile' on configuration container.

Have you got this error before? Do you know how to fix it?
Cheers,

**Comment by [rhnbmpl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30793/rhnbmpl/) on 2017-07-03**:
@hulkbv Sorry, I haven't stared the android part yet. Try consulting android forums for the solution.